# Why is the object assigned to var __webpack_modules__ wrapped in parentheses?

Tags: javascript, webpack

In a bundle.js produced by webpack, there is an expression like this.

```
var __webpack_modules__ = ({...});
```

What is the purpose of these parentheses?

Comment: ensures that its treated as an object expression, not a block

Comment: OK, but why...?

Comment: It's probably a result of modularity in webpack. The function that formats that value might also be used in other contexts where the parentheses are needed.

Comment: @DanielA.White Not necessary in an assignment expression.

Comment: @Barmar Actually no, [the parenthesis are added in the same place as the `=`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/87660921808566ef3b8796f8df61bd79fc026108/lib/javascript/JavascriptModulesPlugin.js#L765-L767). Maybe that was the case previously, and it was just kept for over-cautiousness…